# Understanding that if $E\subset Y\subset X$, then $E$ may be open relative to $Y$ without being an open subset of $X$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose that $X$ is a metric space. Then, clearly $Y$ is also a metric space.  
I understand that $E$ can be open relative to a metric space $X'$ without being a subset of some other metric space $Y'$. That is to say, the fact of a set being "open" is relative, it depends upon the metric space of which the set is being considered as a subset. For example: $(0,1)$ as a subset of $\mathbb R$ is an open set, however as a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ it is closed! because in $\mathbb R^2$, it's a vector.

**Now, with reference to section 2.29 of Rudin's Mathemtical Analysis,**  
Suppose $E\subset Y\subset X$, then "Example 2.21 (g) showed that a set may be open relative to $Y$ without being an open subset of $X$" Now this example is same as stated above (i.e. $(0,1)$ seen as subsets of $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^2$).

**Clearly, $\mathbb R$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$, then how does this example satisfy $E\subset Y\subset X$?** Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Usually in such cases in place of $\mathbb{R}$ is considered set $\{(x,0): x \in \mathbb{R} \}$ and that is understanding as subspace.

Comment: @zkutch: Right. I just wanted to clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first remark: $(0,1)\times\{0\}$ is neither closed nor open in $\Bbb{R}^2;$ the missing edge points $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ prevent it from being closed. You should verify this yourself!

Now, to answer your question, you are correct. Formally, $\Bbb{R}$ is not a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^2.$ However, there are a few natural ways to view $\Bbb{R}$ as a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^2:$ namely, $\Bbb{R}\cong\Bbb{R}\times\{0\}\subseteq\Bbb{R}^2$ and $\Bbb{R}\cong\{0\}\times\Bbb{R}\subseteq\Bbb{R}^2.$ That is, we may view the real numbers as a subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$ by thinking of $\Bbb{R}$ as either the $x$-axis or the $y$-axis! There are infinitely many other ways to do this as well, but these are the two "obvious" candidates. Rudin wants you to think of $\Bbb{R}$ as a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^2$ in one of these ways for the sake of this example.

Comment: Right. I thought so, I just wanted to confirm if I was not wrong. Thanks.